# Are there any bonus for playing 4 v 5 games?

Tags: league-of-legends

We all experienced games where a player leaves or goes AFK mid-game. It is always annoying when you lose a game even though you think you would have won.

Do you get any compensation for playing a game like that? Would it be something like:

- bonus XP/IP
- lost forgiven
- extra bonus if you win the game?

If not do they plan on doing something like that in the future?

Comment: Does a bonus chance to lose count?

Comment: It's a great opportunity to shift blame from yourself to the leaver.

Comment: No, but the AFKers get a bonus buff of magic resist and armor while they AFKing to prevent people from killing them while in the base fountain cuz of their low levels and behindness

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, **No** there is no current compensation, or any plans of a system to do so. However, the system is not completly without forgiveness or mercy and as such Riot has implemented a 'Leave Buster' system, which punishes players for leaving matchmade games early. So no, *you* wont be compensated, but *they* will be punished for leaving.

Comment: You will get a lose forgiven for the first game you lose with a Leaver listed in the end game screen. However, I'm not sure if this only applies to ranked or if it applies to normals as well.

Comment: I thought loss forgiven was only during times of server instability in Ranked queues?

Answer (score 1):

how Ender said, no, probably because people will leave the game to give that bonus to the team and then they will connect. possibly what riot should do is not to let it reconnect after a while and give the bonus.
so far the only thing you get in most cases is a bad game.

Comment: I think they only should give the bonus when the leaver also get a leaverbuster.

Comment: you do realize that to have the leaver portion to count they have to be gone at the end of the game, not at the beginning, and thus they wouldn't receive anything other than the higher status on the leaver buster ban list.

Answer (score 1):

[image: 4 v 5 shyvana game]

So no you won't get anything from winning a 4 v 5 in terms of LP or XP. Any ways I just finished a game were yorik was afk. The only reason he was afk is because he wanted to go top but Lucian picked it first so he rage quit at level 1. I was jungle shyvana and it was a very difficult game to pull one of the most rewarding wins i had in normal games. I think that the best thing 4 v 5 games leave you is the knowledge and the confidence that you can still win. That game was all about me peeling my two adc lol! so yeah don't be discourage.

Answer (score -2):

You must still be in the low level queue's or really bad players on 30s for your win count. So the only thing you will get compensation is satisfaction for winning a 4 v 5. It's the experience you get as you and your team pull of something remarkable and it will last long in your memory.

However, there is a bonus if you do win:

1. You get more lp than your previous game because the game will inevitably last longer.
2. You get better in the game and know how to cooperate with team mates. So teamwork on this criteria.
3. Opponents may give you an honorable opponent recognition.
4. Self-Esteem Boost.

Comment: "You must still be in the low level queue's or really bad players on 30s for your win count." I feel this is an unfair, and perhaps even rude, assumption. 4v5's occur at higher levels as well; it's not like being Gold-ranked automatically stabilises your internet connection and ensures you won't have anything come up in real life.